# RaspberryPi Zero W with battery life for 7 days

Tags: pi-zero-w, battery

I know of different projects that are using micro processors - dont know if they are Raspberry models however - but they have bluetooth connection, wifi module and a camera attached. And they are re-chargeable.

They are mobile, and will last up to 7 days on a charge - with a wifi connection atleast 5 times a day - sometimes with livestream (lowers the days between charge interval), and cURL to webserver also atleast 5 times a day. I assume that it is in standby mode at night and runs a version of example ARCH linux without knowing this for sure.

How is this done? I have searched alot of topics on this, but the consensus seems to be, that the battery time on a good powerbank will only last for about 14 hours. The idea is that it is re-chargeable.

In these two cases (both with raspberry pi zero w):

1. Completely optimized for battery usage - how would this design look like, taking into account Wifi, Camera (webcam), and sending photos example 5 times a day via cURL.
2. Raspberry Pi OS - what battery would give the longest uptime, also with above mentioned parameters?

Comment: You calculate the electrical usage. You buy an appropriate battery. Nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: *"on a good powerbank"* -> Don't use a powerbank, they are intended for recharging things or providing supplementary power to devices (usually mobile = low power by design, which the pi is **not**)  that already have an internal battery and appropriate circuitry.   This is a different task than powering a device with none of the above directly, which has (unlike recharging another battery, what powerbanks are for) rapidly fluctuating current demand.  Pis in general are fickle about power even when plugged into a wall. Get an add on board intended to provide 5V power from a set of batteries.

Comment: And it is going to be a whopper of a set of batteries if you really want to keep these running for 7 days.  Picture *several pounds* worth and something close to a tissue box in size.  For each pi.  *"I assume that it is in standby mode at night"* -> The pi doesn't really have a standby mode, but it does use less power when shutdown.  But to do that you will need something separate to control the power, because the only way they can be restarted is by cycling the power (directly or via control pins on the board).   They really were not designed for this kind of project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be referring to the ESP32-CAM which is a low power micro-processor with WiFi and Bluetooth. You can ge one with a camera for about $10 - $15 on Banggood and other sites.

A Pi Zero W uses about 150 mA of power so for 7 days you'll need a power bank that has a 25 Ah battery at a minimum. A bank with 10 high quality 18650 cells in parallel will work but it will weigh over 1 Kg.

The ESP32 board can go in to a deep sleep and wake up every so often to take pictures or video, this would require a much smaller battery. You can use the Arduino IDE to write the sketch for this.